# regex to match string if a character is found in between (zero width)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match numbers written in a certain pattern. For example :

```
456789   -must not match
123456   -must not match
123 789  -must give 123789
```

I tried this:

```
\d{3}(?= )\d{3}
```

without success. Is this possible with regex alone? If so, how? Or is it asking too much from regex?

Comment: Are you simply trying to remove the space in between the numbers? If that's the case then you can use simple string replacement instead of regex.

Comment: what about 123789 (without space)?

Comment: try `(\d+)\s(\d+)` then use `$1$2` to concat two capture groups

Comment: @BilalAkil I want to match numbers of that pattern from a bunch of text. Yes, i could match it with the space and later replace it but i wanted to know if it was possible with just regex.

Comment: @anupamGak: You cannot match a discontinuous text with a regex. That is when you should either combine matches or capturing groups. They are in regex to let you manipulate the strings the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

Match `(\d{3}) (\d{3})` and replace with `$1$2`?

Comment: Very close. But I m looking to return only the match and not the whole text after replacement. Guess I should just join the capture groups separately. Thanks anyway! 'twas a loads of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this searching with regex alone but to replace you need help.

```
(\d{3})\s(\d{3})
```

this will find the pattern

> 123 789

But to produce

> 123789

you may need any programming language or just `find and replace` of any text editor will do.

replace with `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:
(\d{3} \d{3})

And them replace the " " to ""

Comment: Yes. I can do that. I wanted to know if it could be done with regex alone.